# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am trying to retrieve data from my database table, using this query : `$features = DB::table('features')->get();` and then I want to use it in my view :

```
@foreach ($features as $feature)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $feature->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $feature->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $feature->description }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('adminfeatures.edit',$features->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['adminfeatures.destroy', $features->id]]) !!}
                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

I am getting this error:`Trying to get property of non-object`
I've tried to return $features and its not empty.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Try using the model instead: change `DB::table('features')->get()` to `Features::all()`

Comment: I got another error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Comment: I believe that error comes from this line where you are requesting the 'id' from 'features' instead of 'feature' `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['adminfeatures.destroy', $features->id]]) !!}`

Comment: That's right! Typo  errorr :/

Comment: Fixing that typo, does it also works with `DB::table('features')->get()`?

Comment: Yes it works, you can use either the database facade: DB::.. or the model you created

Comment: Cool, I am glad it worked. You can flag the answer as 'accepted' by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in this line

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['adminfeatures.destroy', $features->id]]) !!}
```

The id request should be done to $feature instead of $feature**s**